# Speeding up loop over dataframes

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have written the code given below. There are two Pandas dataframes: `df` contains columns `timestamp_milli` and `pressure` and `df2` contains columns `timestamp_milli` and `acceleration_z`. Both dataframes have around 100'000 rows. In the code shown below I'm searching for each timestamp of each row of `df` the rows of `df2` where the time difference lies within a range and is minimal.

Unfortunately the code is extremly slow. Moreover, I'm getting the following message originating from the line `df_temp["timestamp_milli"] = df_temp["timestamp_milli"] - row["timestamp_milli"]`:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

How can I speedup the code and solve the warning?

```
acceleration = []
pressure = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    mask = (df2["timestamp_milli"] >= (row["timestamp_milli"] - 5)) & (df2["timestamp_milli"] <= (row["timestamp_milli"] + 5))
    df_temp = df2[mask]

    # Select closest point
    if len(df_temp) > 0:
        df_temp["timestamp_milli"] = df_temp["timestamp_milli"] - row["timestamp_milli"]
        df_temp["timestamp_milli"] = df_temp["timestamp_milli"].abs()

        df_temp = df_temp.loc[df_temp["timestamp_milli"] == df_temp["timestamp_milli"].min()]

        for index2, row2 in df_temp.iterrows():
            pressure.append(row["pressure"])
            acc = row2["acceleration_z"]
            acceleration.append(acc)
```

Comment: For the warning,  I think doing `df_temp = df2[mask].copy()` should prevent it

Comment: If you only want to find the single closest match, then [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) can accomplish this. If you provide sample data and the expected output you can get some  more directed help.

Comment: For starters, dispense with itterrows, which is much slower than itertuples...

Comment: Take a look at using namedtuples. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47149876/6361531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a similar problem, using itertuples instead of iterrows shows significant reduction in time.
[why iterrows have issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
Hope this helps.